# What return on fail googleCloudMessaging.register() method

Tags: android, push-notification, google-api

I am now facing trouble of implementing Push notification. I save return registerId in sharedPreferences. And I have to check that sharedPrefernces is null or empty on fail of googleCloudMessaging.register() method. But I don't know what return on failing register. 
Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should wrap your call to the register() method inside a try-catch statement. Based on the documentation if there is a problem while registering, it should throw an IOException, and you can handle it as you wish. Look at this sample available on the developer's website, it might help you. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html